# How do I make my stored procedure stop producing the error message when it executes properly?

Tags: sql

I'm practicing databases and I'm calling a stored procedure from VS.
It's checking a validation that a given item_num can't be tied to the same cust_ID anywhere else in the table.

The item_num can be duplicated throughout the table, but only when the cust_ID is different.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT * FROM RCUSTOMERS WHERE CUST_ID = @CID AND ITEM_NUM = @INV_NUM
```

And then it's just an error message if they're found tied together.
It sort of works. It returns the error message and won't do anything further if it finds duplicates tied to the same CUST_ID. It also allows for execution if it finds the duplicate NOT tied to the same CUST_ID, the only problem is that it also displays the error message even though it executes. I obviously would prefer it just executing without displaying an error if there is no error.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and stored procedures are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: That's not a stored procedure, that's an SQL query. Show the complete code of your procedure ..